# Mantine ScrollArea doesn't allow full height

Tags: css, mantine

I'm using ScrollArea with `h` property of `100%`, and wrap it with a div with height of `100vh`.
Then for some reason, the ScrollArea adds an additional div in the tree which doesn't take `100%`, so my content inside the scroll area cannot take the height of the parent wrapper, which is `100vh`.
Is there a way to allow the content inside ScrollArea take 100% of the parent wrapper?

**If that sounds a bit confusing, the code is very simple to read:**

```
import { FC } from 'react';

import { ScrollArea } from '@mantine/core';

export const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        <ScrollArea h="100%">
          <div
            style={{
              width: 300,
              height: '100%',
              background: 'orange',
              display: 'flex',
              flexGrow: 1,
            }}
          >
            hello!!
          </div>
        </ScrollArea>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The result:

[image]

As you can see, the orange container doesn't take the `100vh` height of the parent. Please note that I don't want to set the orange container height to `100vh`, and also - it will prevent the scroll area from working properly.

On StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xyrr6a?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: I can't tell you why this is happening, but I figured out that by giving `height: '100vh'` instead of `height: '100%'` to your div, it displays correctly. You could ask rtivital himself through Mantine's Discord. He replies fast and to almost everyone.

Comment: @Alexis yes ofc that will work but it makes more sense to have the height determined in the parent, asked on Discord, thanks for your reply